# How to enable maildir in Dovecot deliver with Sendmail local_procmail

Tags: sendmail, dovecot, procmail, maildir

There is documentation around on how to make `/usr/local/bin/procmail` work with delivering to a maildir.

However, it is my understanding that it is also possible to avoid `procmail` altogether, and have `sendmail`'s `local_procmail` `FEATURE` call `/usr/local/libexec/dovecot/deliver` / `dovecot-lda` directly, instead of first calling `procmail`.

In such case, how would `dovecot-lda` know whether it needs to deliver to mbox or maildir?

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA/Sendmail

```
FEATURE(`local_procmail', `/usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda',`/usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $u')
MODIFY_MAILER_FLAGS(`LOCAL', `-f')
MAILER(procmail)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is decided in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` from what I read in the [manuals](http://www.dovecot.org/doc/dovecot-example.conf). You will need:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes
```